# rcarousel issue - Blank space in image scroll

Tags: jquery

I have a site that I installed the rcarousel on and when I scroll to the right, I see a space between the last image and the first image.

Any one have an idea what causes that?

Here is the site

http://frameworksgallery.com/view_artist2.php?artist_id=Nichols_Karen

scroll to the right.

Answer (score 0):

I think the images are sorted in pages. The first page has a few images, and the second page is not totally filled. If you scroll to the right from the second page, the first page is loaded again.